# Win32 Custom Textbox

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-c++

**Code:**

HWND MyTextField;

```
MyTextField = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW,"EDIT","Window Title :P", WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE, 0,100,105,17,hWnd,(HMENU)SOME_KIND_OF_ID,GetModuleHandle(NULL),NULL);
```

The above provides a white box (textwindow) in which a user can type in. Is there anyway to simulate a textbox, but remove the background color?

I'm trying to place a textbox inside of a chatwindow, but the chat window is black! I cannot have a white textbox inside of a black chat window! Can I make the textbox background transparent?

If possible, I would like to place the carriage return(the blinking vertical line which signifies where a user can type) anywhere I want, without actually having a textbox in the background!

Comment: Try to handle WM_CTLCOLOREDIT message in the parent, setting NULL_BRUSH or any valid brush you need.

Answer (score 1):

As Google said, you should process `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` in parent window
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/285967/winapi-background-color-of-edit